# Saving Email attachment - "Cannot save the attachment. Path does not exist." - pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

**Objective of the program:**

I have a python script that searches my `Outlook` inbox for an email with a specific subject and if found will save the attachment on the email to a specific path.

The script executes as expected when the path chosen to save the file is on my C: drive, however I would like to save the file on a shared O: drive and this results in an error when saving the attachment.

**Error I am getting:**

However, I get the below error

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 19, in
>      File ">", line 2, in SaveAsFile
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096,
>   'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot save the attachment. Path does not exist.
>   Verify the path is correct.', None, 0, -2147024893), None)"

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Given the script executes as expected for the C: drive it doesn't seem like the path is invalid for the O: drive.

**My research effort:**

Below is the code:

```py
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
file_path_that_works = "C:/Users/kennedj/Desktop/projects"
file_path_that_does_not_work = "O:/projects"

for message in messages:
    if message.Subject == 'Specific Subject':
        attachments = message.Attachments
        for attachment in attachments:
            new_file_name = 'excel attachment {}.xls'.format(now)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(file_path_that_does_not_work , new_file_name))
            break
        message.Delete()
```

Comment: Maybe theres a problem noticing the drive? If you do: import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
print(drives) does the drive then exist?

Comment: Yes I can see the O drive that doesn't work - I have a work around with  shutil.move(os.path.join(file_path_that_does_not_work , new_file_name), file_path_that_works )